# Lubuntu lxpanel fails to display icons correctly in vertical mode

Tags: lubuntu, indicator, lxpanel

LXPanel 0.8.2 in Lubuntu 16.04. The indicator applet in the panel works flawlessly in a horizontal panel, but in a vertical one it still displays the application icons next to each other horizontally instead of vertically. One can see this by changing the panel's width:

- doubled width: two symbols [image: doubled width]
- 1 1/2 width: one symbol plus the half of another
- normal width: just one of the symbols

What can I do to get the indicator area to display the symbols vertically?

Comment: As you can see the bug has been around for a long time and prevent us from using a vertical LXPanel.  Not a big deal unless of course you wanted a vertical panel.

Comment: @Rex And nobody cares about it although this sort of prevents one from using the feature at all? I'm a little bit disappointed…

Comment: As you can see the issue was raised in 2013 and still no action.  There are those of us who have been with Lubuntu from before its "official" recognition and we keep plugging along.  These little bugs that really do not affect the operation do not get priority because the Lubuntu Team is not large and is not capable of doing everything.  That was one of the reasons that our first LTS release was 14.04.  Manpower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's a long known bug that has not been fixed yet. The bug report can be found [here on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1258789). If it affects you please click “this affects me” on that page to let the developers know.